# Multi thread updating value java

Tags: java, multithreading

We have  2 threads:

- they have no task scheduling
- they also have no synchronization mechanisms

Their task is:

- to read a value into a register
- increment the value in the register
- write the value back to location X

At start X contains value 0. Both threads modify value at same location.

Both threads start at the same time and do 1000 iterations.

Question: What is the smallest value X after both threads finish? 
(not 1000 and not 2000)

Comment: is "into a register" well defined for Java?

Comment: Well, what do *you* think and why?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Because it seriously sounds like that. In that case, please provide at least some words on what you think the solution is and where you are unsure.

Comment: you can use [Atomic Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html)

Comment: @AurA That is **NOT** true at all. `volatile` is *not* a substitute for proper synchronization. (edit: Suggestion before the edit was to use `volatile`)

Comment: @AurA Also, how do atomic variables have anything to do with the question?

Comment: It's a homework question indeed. And I suspect it's 2000.

Comment: you suspect correctly...

Comment: But than there is the question why?

Comment: @user3580294 the reading the value in a register... you can use atomic variable or volatile keyword for the single variable. For multiple values you need a blocking queue to take care of syncronisation

Comment: @AurA volatile ensures that changes to the variable in one thread are visible to annother and atomic variables allow certain operations (which are usually several operations on the CPU) to be considered a single operation so can't be interleaved with others. But they make no further promises

Comment: @AurA That is true, but you're trying to answer a nonexistent question. Read OP's question carefully.

Comment: @notanormie Well, why do you think the answer is 2000?

Comment: The instructor says 1000 isn't the answer...

Comment: if the updates from one thread are completely ignored all the times then i think the minimum value should be 1000

Comment: Well thanks. Will do some more research into it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The smallest possible number is 2.

```
T1 reads the value 0.
T2 increments X 999 times to 999.
T1 writes the value 1
T2 reads the value 1
T1 increments X 999 times to 1000
T2 writes the value 2.
```

Comment: And there it is. I was sure that the answer was either 1 or 2, but I couldn't figure out the sequence of events to do that. +1.

Comment: +1 Well done. I kept trying to think of a solution like this but couldn't fathom it. Nice succinct explanation too.

Comment: I thought it should somewhere around 1 +- 1. Thanks!